# Filter a column's row by its value in another column and then do the sum

Tags: google-sheets

Please see the spreadsheet below,

[image]

The total is calculated by summing all the rows straight, But I want to calculate the `Paid` by summing each row of B column but only if the rows have "paid" value at D column. Please I need to know the formula to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sumif like this:

```
=sumif(D2:D,"paid",B2:B)
```